# If bivector exponentials are rotations, what are translation?

Tags: matrices, geometry, vectors, matrix-exponential, clifford-algebras

It is well known that a rotation is given by the bivector exponentials, such as:

$$
e^{\frac{ \mathbf{B}}{2}} \mathbf{x} e^{-\frac{ \mathbf{B}}{2}}
$$

where $\mathbf{B}$ is a bivector and $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector.

I am trying to find the geometric effect of:

$$
e^{\frac{\mathbf{v}}{2}} \mathbf{x} e^{-\frac{\mathbf{v}}{2}}
$$

where $\mathbf{v}$ is a vector. Is it a translation? If not, what is it?

Comment: Have you written the expression in any other forms? Have you had trouble manipulating/summarizing the algebra here?

Comment: @MarkS. Well $e^{a \mathbf{v}/2}=\cosh a+ \mathbf{v}/||\mathbf{v}|| \sinh a$. The only reference I have found since then is that the exponential of a one-vector represents a hyperbolic versor, which was later found to be connected to a Lorentz Boost. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versor#Hyperbolic_versor So is this the interpretation? If so, I cannot make $e^{\mathbf{v}/2}$ correspond to a Lorentz boost - can anyone help?

Comment: I may have a chance to check my algebra tomorrow, but if $\theta=|\mathbf v|$ and $\mathbf j=\mathbf v/\theta$, then I think I got $e^{-\mathbf v/2}\mathbf xe^{\mathbf v/2}=(\cosh\theta)\mathbf x-(\sinh\theta)(\mathbf j\wedge\mathbf x)+(1-\cosh\theta)(\mathbf j\cdot\mathbf x)\mathbf j$. But there are *many* places I could have made a sign error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\mathbf{j}=\dfrac{\mathbf{v}}{\left|\mathbf{v}\right|}$ and $\theta=\left|\mathbf{v}\right|$. We may want to write $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}_{\parallel}+\mathbf{x}_{\perp}$ where $\mathbf{x}_{\parallel}=\left(\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{j}\right)\mathbf{j}$. Note that $\mathbf{jxj}=\mathbf{jxj}^{-1}$ is the reflection of $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathbf{j}$: $\mathbf{x}_{\parallel}-\mathbf{x}_{\perp}$, or $2\mathbf{x}_{\parallel}-\mathbf{x}$. In analogy with rotations where the convention is to have the minus sign in the first factor, consider:

\begin{align}&\phantom{=}e^{-\mathbf{v}/2}\mathbf{x}e^{\mathbf{v}/2}\\&=e^{-\mathbf{j}\theta/2}\mathbf{x}e^{\mathbf{j}\theta/2}\\
&=\left(\cosh\dfrac{\theta}{2}-\mathbf{j}\sinh\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)\mathbf{x}\left(\cosh\dfrac{\theta}{2}+\mathbf{j}\sinh\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)\\
&=\mathbf{x}\cosh^{2}\dfrac{\theta}{2}-\mathbf{jxj}\sinh^{2}\dfrac{\theta}{2}+\left(\mathbf{xj}-\mathbf{jx}\right)\sinh\dfrac{\theta}{2}\cosh\dfrac{\theta}{2}\\
&=\mathbf{x}\cosh^{2}\dfrac{\theta}{2}-\mathbf{jxj}\sinh^{2}\dfrac{\theta}{2}+\left(\mathbf{xj}-\mathbf{jx}\right)\sinh\dfrac{\theta}{2}\cosh\dfrac{\theta}{2}\\
&=\mathbf{x}\cosh^{2}\dfrac{\theta}{2}-\mathbf{jxj}\sinh^{2}\dfrac{\theta}{2}+\left(\mathbf{x}\wedge\mathbf{j}\right)2\sinh\dfrac{\theta}{2}\cosh\dfrac{\theta}{2}\\
&=\mathbf{x}\cosh^{2}\dfrac{\theta}{2}-\left(\mathbf{x}_{\parallel}-\mathbf{x}\right)\sinh^{2}\dfrac{\theta}{2}+\left(\mathbf{x}\wedge\mathbf{j}\right)2\sinh\dfrac{\theta}{2}\cosh\dfrac{\theta}{2}\\
&=\mathbf{x}\left(\cosh^{2}\dfrac{\theta}{2}+\sinh^{2}\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)-2\mathbf{x}_{\parallel}\sinh^{2}\dfrac{\theta}{2}+\left(\mathbf{x}\wedge\mathbf{j}\right)2\sinh\dfrac{\theta}{2}\cosh\dfrac{\theta}{2}\\
&=\mathbf{x}\cosh\theta-2\mathbf{x}_{\parallel}\sinh^{2}\dfrac{\theta}{2}+\left(\mathbf{x}\wedge\mathbf{j}\right)\sinh\theta\\
&=\mathbf{x}\cosh\theta-\mathbf{x}_{\parallel}\left(\cosh\theta-1\right)+\left(\mathbf{x}\wedge\mathbf{j}\right)\sinh\theta\\
&=\mathbf{x}\cosh\theta+\mathbf{x}_{\parallel}\left(1-\cosh\theta\right)+\left(\mathbf{x}\wedge\mathbf{j}\right)\sinh\theta\\
&=\left(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_{\parallel}\right)\cosh\theta+\mathbf{x}_{\parallel}+\left(\mathbf{x}\wedge\mathbf{j}\right)\sinh\theta\\
&=\boxed{\mathbf{x}_{\perp}\cosh\theta+\left(\mathbf{x}_{\perp}\wedge\mathbf{j}\right)\sinh\theta+\mathbf{x}_{\parallel}}\end{align}

So it has aspects reminiscent of a Lorentz boost, but there is a bivector there and the parallel component is unaffected.

---

We can also compare this formula to the rotation formulas. To rotate $\mathbf x$ in a plane $\mathbf I$ by an angle $\theta$, we use $e^{-\mathbf{I}\theta/2}\mathbf{x}e^{\mathbf{I}\theta/2}=\mathbf{x}_{\parallel}e^{\mathbf{I}\theta}+\mathbf{x}_{\perp}$ (here $\mathbf{x}_{\parallel}$ means the part that's in the plane $\mathbf I$). And the above calculation shows that we have an analogous $e^{-\mathbf{j}\theta/2}\mathbf{x}e^{\mathbf{j}\theta/2}=\mathbf{x}_{\perp}e^{\mathbf{j}\theta}+\mathbf{x}_{\parallel}$. If $\mathbf j=\mathbf J^*$, we might also write $\mathbf x_{\perp}\wedge\mathbf J^*$ as $\left(\mathbf x_\perp\cdot\mathbf J\right)^*$ (using the left contraction).

But no matter what we do, since the result is a sum of a bivector part and a vector part, it can't really have as tidy a visualization as a vector or a bivector, etc.

Comment: That's very interesting. Thank you. Any idea what the 'physical' or geometric interpretation could be? What kind of transformation are we doing with this? If we instead were to use a bivector instead of a vector $\exp ( \theta \mathbf{B}/2 ) \mathbf{x}  \exp (-\theta \mathbf{B}/2)$ we get usual rotations --- something relatively simple to grasp. Can we understand $\exp ( a \mathbf{v}/2 ) \mathbf{x}  \exp (- a \mathbf{v}/2)$ in 'visualisable' terms?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay I added some words comparing it to the rotation formula, but the result isn't just a vector or even a bivector, so I don't think there's hope of a relatively simple geometric picture.

Comment: Can I get your thoughts on this link: http://peeterjoot.com/2018/01/14/lorentz-boosts-in-geometric-algebra-paravector-notation/. They essentially perform the same sequence of steps as you have done here, except that they start with what they call a "space-time split", which seems to just be a multiplication of $\mathbf{x}$ by $\gamma_0$. The result is $\mathbf{s}=X_0+X_1 \gamma_1\gamma_0+X_2 \gamma_2\gamma_0+X_3 \gamma_3\gamma_0$, which they describe as a "lab reference frame". The applying $\exp(a\mathbf{v}/2) \mathbf{s} \exp(-a\mathbf{v}/2)$ yields exactly the Lorentz boost.  (contd).

Comment: (contd) Here, we essentially do the same but without the initial "space-time split". Can we then understand our transformation as a completely observer-independent Lorentz transformation, unlike the usual one which appears to require picking the "lab reference frame"?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay You seem to be missing or misunderstanding a lot of the context in and around that article, and I can't clear everything up in a comment or two. 1. The spacetime split is to make the spacetime algebra as described at the beginning of the article. 2. Multiplication by $\gamma_0$ is to convert to paravector notation, which you could do without the split. 3. Neither of the above things is the "lab frame"; they just use that phrase to emphasize that $\gamma_0$ is before any boost. 4. Stuff in special relativity depends on the observer; correct math would not overturn that.